Sorting tiles by total (sum) size of parent node in a D3.js treemap
I generated the treemap below using the D3.js library. Parent nodes are filled in gray, leaves are filled white.

However, despite setting the sorting based on the values (determined by attribute "asize") of my json file, I can't get the treemap to be properly sorted by size.
Here is the excerpt in my js.
const valueKey = 'asize';
  
const root = d3.hierarchy(data)
  .sum(d => d[valueKey])
  .sort((a, b) =>  b[valueKey] - a[valueKey]);

Sample json to show format, "asize" attribute contains the values.
{
    "name": "budget",
    "children": [
        {
            "name": ".git",
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "config",
                    "asize": 298,
                    "ino": 2533274790936458
                },
                {
                    "name": "description",
                    "asize": 73,
                    "ino": 1688849860804465
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

The relative size of budget and allcharts tiles is consistent with their total size (ncdu output below); however no sorting seems to be happening in the treemap.
    2.1 MiB [##########] /budget
  148.0 KiB [          ] /allcharts
  100.0 KiB [          ] /zoomableD3
   96.0 KiB [          ] /nested-treemap
   72.0 KiB [          ] /zoom
   12.0 KiB [          ] /sample3
   12.0 KiB [          ] /treemap

